# Is it semantically correct to use <h1> in a dialog?

Tags: html, dialog, accessibility, wai-aria

I've gone through the code for [The Incredible Accesible Dialog v3](https://accessibility.oit.ncsu.edu/training/aria/modal-window/version-3/) and i have noticed that they are using an `<h1>` tag

```
<div id="modal" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-describedby="modalDescription" role="dialog">
    <div id="modalDescription" class="screen-reader-offscreen">...</div>
    <h1 id="modalTitle">...</h1>
    <p>...</p>
    <form name="form1" onsubmit="return false;">...</form>
</div>
```

So that got me thinking, is that actually semantically correct? I mean everyone keeps saying there should only be 1 `<h1>` in a document.

Note that in previous versions of the dialog, they gave the dialog a `role="document"` which  makes using `<h1>` ok imho

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I know you have accepted an answer, but it is not quite right.

Sure, you can put an `<h1>` in a dialog and nothing will catch fire. It will technically not be correct, however.

The heading level should represent where it lives in the page structure. If your page has a single `<h1>`, which is your best way to go, then the dialog should get a heading level that corresponds to where it lives within the structure of the page (its content).

Most likely the dialog does not fit into the flow of the rest of the content, so it would appropriately be a sub of the page's `<h1>` (since it is a dialog about the page), making the dialog take `<h2>`.

If you are using a tabbed interface, and you have built your tabs to each be `<h2>`s, and your dialog applies to a specific tab, then your dialog would take an `<h3>`.

And so on.

Adding `role=document` does not change this (and [may be a mis-application of the `document` ARIA role](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-1.1/roles#document) unless you are explicitly testing with assistive technology to ensure it works as you expect).

You can see that the [all-`<h1>` model is now considered an anti-pattern in HTML 5.1](http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements). The [W3C HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) will now flag it.

You can read more about the approach to structure headings in an article penned by one of the editors of the HTML5 spec: [Computer says NO to HTML5 document outline](http://html5doctor.com/computer-says-no-to-html5-document-outline/)

So, to answer your original question, no it is not semantically correct to use `<h1>` in a dialog.

Comment: While I do agree with you, the interesting thing is that in the spec there is no mention of this "rule". I checked before even posting this question. And yes the dialog I was looking at (The Incredible Accesible Dialog) is in fact tested with a number of screen readers (listed at the bottom), so they would not use ARIA roles lightly.

Comment: 1. The spec does mention the `<h1>` "rule" and has [had a warning since HTML5.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#outlines) along with [open bugs](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Usage/Headings/h1only#Notes) to fix it. 2. See the [blog post about the dialog](https://accessibility.oit.ncsu.edu/blog/2015/02/13/the-incredible-accessible-modal-window-version-3/): "removed the role=”document” from the contents of the window. This was originally inserted to deal with the way NVDA interacted with role=”dialog”, but that issue has since been resolved in NVDA."

Comment: As of October 2020, the first example in "§ 4.3.3 The section element" states: "Notice how the use of section means that the author can use h1 elements throughout, without having to worry about whether a particular section is at the top level, the second level, the third level, and so on." See: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element

Comment: Which is incredibly frustrating considering it also lists `<hgroup>` (which has no support) and leans on the Document Outline Algorithm which has _never_ been implemented. So if you are supporting users, ignore that part of the spec. If you are targeting code compliance, go nuts. Ref: https://adrianroselli.com/2016/08/there-is-no-document-outline-algorithm.html, https://codepen.io/stevef/post/a-decade-of-heading-backwards

Comment: This again depends on the context of the dialog – `dialog` does however not appear to be a **sectioning content** or **section root** element, which is inconsistent and a bit odd given it can be useful to give dialogs a heading. I can not find any WHATWG mention of it being "sectioning root" anymore, but it used to say this in w3 specifications: https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-html53-20180809/sections.html#sectioning-roots

Not sure if this means we should avoid using headings entirely in dialogs, and perhaps use something else, like a more neutral `p` or `div` however.

Answer (score 3):

Semantically, you can start any new section of the document  (section, article, nav, aside, header, footer) with an `h1`.

It will change with HTML 5.1, but `h1` might still be used in `dialog` (*) elements because they are considered as "sectioning roots". See http://w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#headings-and-sections).

> Certain elements are said to be sectioning roots, including blockquote and td elements. These elements can have their own outlines, but the sections and headings inside these elements do not contribute to the outlines of their ancestors.
>
> `blockquote` `body` `details` `dialog` `fieldset` `figure` `td`

**Because of the lack of support by browsers and accessibility technologies, although it's "semantically" correct, this does not mean that it's a good design choice**. Authors should prefer preserving the h1..h6 hierarchy across sections to have a coherent, hierarchized/nested document outline (`h1`>`h2`>`h3`>...`h6`) which will be provided to assistive technologies.

(*) *Note that, as pointed by another user, it will then be necessary to use a `dialog` rather than a `role=dialog` element to have full support.*

Comment: This is no longer true (and has never worked as originally proposed): http://html5doctor.com/computer-says-no-to-html5-document-outline/

Comment: I disagree that it is semantically valid. Semantically, you are saying the dialog is a peer to the page as a whole, when it is not. It is defined within the context of the page. This is not new in HTML 5.1, this reflects how the `<h#>` elements were designed from day one.

Comment: Except, a) OP is not using the `<dialog>` element, b) having its own outline still does not matter since no browser supports the outline algorithm and it has been noted in [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#outlines) and [HTML5.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#creating-an-outline) that it should be avoided and c) the W3C link you offer even says "Authors should use headings of the appropriate rank for the section’s nesting level."

Comment: a) No, `role=dialog` is not equivalent to `<dialog>`. Adding a `role` never makes it equivalent, whether for the browser or assistive technology, it just exposes some of its aspects (which is why you still have to script keyboard support for `role=button`). b) Semantics are different from structure. `<h#>` imparts both, `<strong>` imparts only semantics. Technology support is important for AT, so yeah, we are talking about that. c) You are unclear. Regardless, it is still not semantically correct.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, and helping me improving my answer.

Comment: Adam, did you delete your other comments or is my browser getting all wonky? If so, my comments look like I am shouting at clouds (which is always appropriate in my case).

Comment: @aardrian Yes. I attached too much importance on the word "semantic" (no matter if we disagree on its definition), while you rightly pointed the lack of browser support which is more important than the question itself.

Comment: aardrian has a point, but even outside of the context of the *not-implemented document outline*, there are still times when a `dialog` calls for its own `h1`; E.g. The context might be "the page as a whole", such is the case for GDPR consent dialogs. Point is, Having multiple `h1`s is actually valid. Nothing in the specification prohibits it, and sometimes it is indeed semantically valid, other times it is simply personal preference. Multiple h1's remain useful when used right (just not when used exclusively).